# How to get the text with in the datatemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used below code

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
```

in this case i can able to get the textblock text by using below code

```
DataTemplate myTemplate = this.Resources["myTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
  TextBlock rootElement = myTemplate.LoadContent() as TextBlock;
  //I can get the text "rootElement.text "
```

but when i use binding means i cant able to get the text

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeName}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You already have value in `EmployeeName` in `DataContext/ViewModel`, why are you trying to get it again via CodeBehind, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, have you `applied` this template to some element? I think, bindings on templates get into picture only after them getting applied for some `data`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get access to an element that was defined inside a `DataTemplate`, we first need to get hold of a `ContentPresenter`. We can get the `ContentPresenter` from an item that has had the `DataTemplate` applied to it. We can then access the `DataTemplate` from the `ContentPresenter` and then access its elements using the `FindName` method. Here is an example from the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx) page on MSDN, which you should read for full details:

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem 
// Note that the ListBox must have 
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)
    (myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)
    myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);

// Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
MessageBox.Show("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: " + 
    myTextBlock.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplates` are like blueprints, that describes how a particular data should be displayed on the screen. DataTemplates are just resources. They can be sshared by multiple elements. [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) are not derived from `FrameworkElement`, so they cannot have `DataContext`/`Databinding` on their own. When you apply a `DataTemplate` to some element, it is implicitly given an appropriate data context.

So, I guess, you wont be able to get bounded data unless you apply the template to something.

Answer (score 0):

When using `DataBinding` you CAN get text and even easier. Only thing that you should keep in mind is `DataContext` of your template. If you're using template in a `ListBox` - then context will be particular `Item` i.e:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string EmployeeName 
    {
       get 
       {
          return this.employeeName;
       }
       set 
       {
          this.employeeName = value;
          this.OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
       }
    }

    ...
}
```

In `ViewModel`:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
       get
       {
           return this.employees;
       }
       set
       {
          this.employees = value;
          this.OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
       }
    }

    ...    
}
```

And `xaml`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Employees}>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeName}"></TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

With such structure you'll have

```
ListBox    | Value source
Employee0  | (Employees[0].EmployeeName)
Employee1  | (Employees[1].EmployeeName)
...        | ...
EmployeeN  | (Employees[n].EmployeeName)
```